# List objects in S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3, sdk

I am trying to list all files in a bucket.

This returns empty array:

```
$objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => "mybucket",
    "Prefix" => "/sub/folder/"
));
```

And this...

```
$objects = $s3Client->listObjects(['Bucket' => "mybucket", 'Prefix' => "/sub/folder/"]);
```

... returns this:

```
Aws\Result Object
(
    [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
            [IsTruncated] => 
            [Marker] => 
            [Name] => mybucket
            [Prefix] => /sub/folder/
            [MaxKeys] => 1000
            [EncodingType] => url
            [@metadata] => Array
                (
                    [statusCode] => 200
                    [effectiveUri] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket?prefix=%2Fsub%2Ffolder%2F&encoding-type=url
                    [headers] => Array
                        (
                            [x-amz-id-2] => ........
                            [x-amz-request-id] => .....
                            [date] => Sat, 01 Feb 2020 14:19:02 GMT
                            [x-amz-bucket-region] => us-east-1
                            [content-type] => application/xml
                            [server] => AmazonS3
                            [connection] => close
                        )

                    [transferStats] => Array
                        (
                            [http] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [monitoringEvents:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

There are five files in this bucket. The bucket is public, and I have tried already listing the root. But I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake.

```
'Bucket' => "mybucket", # this can't have any slash
'Prefix' => "sub/folder/" # this can't start with a slash
```